# I want to left pad a column value by zeros in pig latin script using python udf

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-pig

I followed the steps below zeropad.py My python script

```
!/usr/bin/python

from org.apache.pig.scripting import *

@outputSchema('time:int')

def zero():
    time.zfill(4)
```

=======================================

grunt>REGISTER 'zeropad.py' using org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;

==============================

```
Airlines_data_schema = LOAD 'AirlinesData_sample-1.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,DepTime_actual:int,CRSDeptime:int,Arrtime_actual:int,CRSArrtime:int,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay);
```

===================================================

```
 airlines_new = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema GENERATE Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,myfuncs.zero.DepTime_actual AS DepTime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero.CRSDeptime AS CRSDeptime_new,myfuncs.zero.Arrtime_actual AS Arrtime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero.CRSArrtime AS CRSArrtime_new,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay ;
```

I am getting the following error

```
2017-02-26 19:37:19,606 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
```

Invalid field projection. Projected field [myfuncs] does not exist in schema: Year:bytearray,Month:bytearray,DayofMonth:bytearray,DayofWeek:bytearray,DepTime_actual:int,CRSDeptime:int,Arrtime_actual:int,CRSArrtime:int,UniqueCarrier:bytearray,FlightNum:bytearray,TailNum_Plane:bytearray,ActualElapsedTime:bytearray,CRSElapsedTime:bytearray,Airtime:bytearray,Arrdelay:bytearray,Depdelay:bytearray,Origin:bytearray,Dest:bytearray,Distance:bytearray,Taxiin:bytearray,Taxiout:bytearray,Cancelled:bytearray,CancellationCode:bytearray,Diverted:bytearray,CarrierDelay:bytearray,WeatherDelay:bytearray,NASDelay:bytearray,SecurityDelay:bytearray,LateAircraftDelay:bytearray.

Wanted to know Why am I not able to use my python function to manipulate my column value

Comment: please use comments in place of new answers !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to left pad a column value by zeros in pig latin using python udf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458902/i-want-to-left-pad-a-column-value-by-zeros-in-pig-latin-using-python-udf)

Comment: Please don't repost questions if they're closed—edit and **fix the problems** that were highlighted last time you posted the exact same text as this post.

Comment: There was nothing highlighted that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax :

```
airlines_new = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema GENERATE Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek, myfuncs.zero(DepTime_actual) AS DepTime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero.CRSDeptime AS CRSDeptime_new,myfuncs.zero.Arrtime_actual AS Arrtime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero.CRSArrtime AS CRSArrtime_new,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!!! With the small correction indicated below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("num:int")

def zero(time):
        return time.zfill(4);


REGISTER '/home/Jig13517/zeropad.py' using jython AS func ;


airlines_new = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema GENERATE Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,func.zero(Airlines_data_schema.DepTime_actual) AS DepTime_actual_new:int,func.zero(Airlines_data_schema.CRSDeptime) AS CRSDeptime_new:int,func.zero(Airlines_data_schema.Arrtime_actual) AS Arrtime_actual_new:int,func.zero(Airlines_data_schema.CRSArrtime) AS CRSArrtime_new:int,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay ;
```